# Не подгружается драйвер QMYSQL

Tags: mysql, qt

В Qt 5.6.1 идет драйвер QMYSQL. При работе программы вылетает с:

> QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
>     QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Загружал MySQL Connector C. Брал оттуда libmysql.dll и кидал в папку со сборкой программы (на моем другом ноутбуке это срабатывало). Не выходит.
Работаю на Windows XP SP3.
Почему не получается?

Если что, собрать самому драйвер не выйдет. Комп не мой.

Answer (score 0):

libmysql.dll нужна именно из комплекта установленного MySQL. При запуске приложения из QtCreator она должна лежать на уровень выше ехе-шника. При запуске из проводника - в каталоге с ехе.